# Are there any bugs/problems in using Materialized Views?

Tags: cassandra, materialized-views, nosql

We extensively use materialized views in our micro service but have the Cassandra Cluster managed by the 3rd party.

We are facing latency issues and vendor is insisting on not using views as they say it's buggy.

Are materialized Views Buggy? Thoughts?

Comment: a recent email thread on topic: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-dev/201707.mbox/%3CCAPbVhuN5Coz9uEW1F3V-7PrbfcSAR=909xiAEbSReMZ_6WuKyA@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Write latency ?? Each Materialized View will cost you 10% write latency on your base table

Answer (score 0):

These are the only 3/10 referenced in the apache.org archive linked by Chris above that are still open/pending:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12888
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12730
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10346

The rest have been resolved.